# verify connection in jersey

Tags: java, rest, servlets, jersey, jax-rs

I want to be able to verify that the connection is still alive (client not dead) when sending a response from a Jersey (jax-rs) resource. The reason is that if I just return the response object and the client is dead, the response is lost without knowing that the client did not receive it.

Comment: You'd need a second request from the client to acknowledge that it's been received. HTTP is request response, so once the client makes the request, it's game over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
httpContext.getResponse().setResponse(myResponse)
try {
  httpContext.getResponse().getOutputStream().write(new byte[]{})
} catch (Exception e) {
  // writing of headers failed. 
}
```